# How to get the uploaded file path in FilePicker

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

Currently we are able to drag and drop the folders and we are able to get all the files in the folder.
but we are not able to get the path of that files.

How can we get the file path of the files which are uploaded, so that we can maintain the same folder structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response from filepicker you receive list of objects.
Each object looks like this:

```
{
     "url":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/0SIihoHPT8ORvwQ3EOPx",
     "filename":"filepicker_test.png",
     "mimetype":"image/png",
     "size":4607,
     "id":4,
     "path":"/2/folder/filepicker_test.png",
     "isWriteable":true
}
```

So you can restore directories structure using "path" key from filepicker answer.